# Printing an array in JOptionPane

Tags: java, arrays, printing, joptionpane

```
public String show(int[] row)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < row.length; i++)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, row[i]);
        }
    }
```

What is wrong with this code?
I just want to print an array which is given in the parameter.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve, what is the result and what you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the return type to `void`:

```
public void show(int[] row) {
```

Also, if you wish to display all elements in the array you could do:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Arrays.toString(row));
```

If a return `String` is needed the same approach can be used:

```
return Arrays.toString(row);
```

Comment: This would be a helpfull solution, but it has to have a returntype String. It is a ex which we haven't made in class which I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
public String show(int[] row) {
  String returnValue = Arrays.toString(row);
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, returnValue);

  return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is similar to my solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void show(int[] row)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < row.length; i++)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, row[i]);
        }
    return;
    }
```

Or...

```
public String show(int[] row)
    {
        String s = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < row.length; i++)
        {
            s  += row[i]);
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s);
        return s;
    }
```

Or...

```
public String show(int[] row)
        {
            String s = "";
            for(int i = 0; i < row.length; i++)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, row[i]);
                s  += row[i]);
            }
            return s;
        }
```